# Binning large set of tuples into ternary grid for heatmap

Tags: python, python-3.x, heatmap, ternary, binning

I have produce a set of coordinates that correspond to x,y,z(not cartesian but ternary) and a set of ternary grid. Since most of the results are requires high resolution in order to give a clear heatmap, my ternary grid ended up being ridiculously large which I can't be avoided.

Coor(ternary grid) has around ~500,000 tuples and N(data)~ 100,000, both having the same type of type of coordinates. This resulted in quite an absurd amount of computing time. each N is binned into Coor which later I would use it to plot the heat map. I am doing this on python 3.4. below is a snippet of the code that is taking long computing time.

```
for i in range(Coor):
    for k in range(N):
        if all(coor[i])==all(data1[k]):
            value110[i]=(value110[i]+1.0)
```

Is there any way that I could simplifies the binning process or make the binning process on python much faster? There isn't much topic on the net around binning for a ternary plot which leads me asking here.

```
data110=[(0.53,0.23,0.24),(0.55,0.18,0.26),....]
Coor=[(0.0,0.0,1.0),(0.0,0.01,0.99),(0.0,0.02,0.98).....] #this would be the ternary grid (bottom axis,right axis,left axis)
```

value110 would be a set of zeros corresponds to the Coor(ternary grid).

```
value110=np.zeros(len(Coor))
```

Each zero in value110 is a floating point correspond to the ternary grid(They represent the heat level at each ternary grid)

data110 could take any value on the grid as they are randomly generated through a function.

[an example of heatmap i plotted with a smaller sample size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly5cN.png)

I am increasing the number of sample in order to give a much smoother transition in each bin. The point on the ternary grid that are correspond to 0, I have omitted from the data(lessen the need of ram when plotting). Problem arises when I am trying to enlarge my samples but the binning process is not that very efficient anymore so I am trying to improve the speed of binning it

Comment: What are you trying to do?  This doesn't look like binning.

Comment: Consider posting a *runnable* complete example. Right now I can't make sense of your question or the example.

Comment: I am not trying to do the traditional binning that take a range of value to a bin as it would get pretty confusing when I am trying to plot. https://github.com/marcharper/python-ternary on this website there are some example of heatmap